# LinearLayout with ConstraintLayout and padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to have a layout with 3 images that has space between them, but i have a textview below every image and i would like the textview to be 20dp larger in width from the images.

```
<LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="top"
       android:weightSum="6"
       android:orientation="horizontal">
       <Space
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="2" />
       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:paddingLeft="@dimen/abc_action_bar_content_inset_with_nav"
           android:paddingRight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_content_inset_with_nav"
           android:orientation="vertical">
           <ImageButton
               android:src="@drawable/ic_sad"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/SadImageButton"
               android:background="@null"
               android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
           <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout      
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/SadTextTextView"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:visibility="gone"
               app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
               android:minLines="4"
               android:maxLines="4"
               app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
           </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
       <Space
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1" />
       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:orientation="vertical">
           <ImageButton
               android:src="@drawable/ic_neutral"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/NeutralImageButton"
               android:background="@null"
               android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
           <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/NeutralTextTextView"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:visibility="gone"
               android:minLines ="4"
               android:maxLines ="4"
               app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
               app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
           </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
       <Space
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1" />
       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:orientation="vertical">
           <ImageButton
               android:src="@drawable/ic_happy"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:id="@+id/HappyImageButton"
               android:background="@null"
               android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
           <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent">
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/HappyTextTextView"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:visibility="gone"
               android:maxLines ="4"
               app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
           </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
       </LinearLayout>
       <Space
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="2" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

I have try adding padding to the layout that holds the image with the textview or to the textview but i can't manage to do what i want, any ideas?

This is the look of the iamges without text
[image: Image without text]
and this is what im getting without the constraint layout
[image: image with text]
If i use constraint layout the width of the test is equal to the image, i want it to be larger.

Comment: Can you draw what you mean? or your imagination?! I see your code too complex so rendering will be costly

Comment: Imagine having 3 images in a row and between them space (so 4 spaces. Below every image there is a textview, i want the textview to be a bit larger than the imageview. something like textview's maxwidth=imageview.width*1.2)

Comment: need text to be shifted or just width of text view?

Comment: to be equally larger in right and let. if the image is 100dp and the textview is 120dp i would like them to be aligned center vertically

Comment: have you tried to set textview constraints to imageview and use `        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"` which means if text width exceed it goes to next line

Comment: if i set the constrains to the imageview how i can have the textview larger?

Comment: 1.2 larger if fixed val? if yes, set space width to specific val and set constrain of textview right to the right of the space

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to get something like this:

[image: Screenshot]

And here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_red"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_green"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_blue"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: i would like all 3 texviews to have the same size, every textview will have different size so with app:autoSizeTextType i think i will have different size for each textview which is not pretty

Comment: you can add android:layout_weight="1" for your inner LinearLayouts then they all will have equal sizes and set android:layout_width="match_parent" for TextViews.

Comment: but if the textview has width that matches the parent how are going to be bigger from the imageview?

Comment: Due to margins imageview has offsets from left and right

Comment: still with your solution every textview will have its own size, according to the text, i want all the text sizes of the 3 textviews to be the same

Comment: Then you can try to set android:layout_width to specific value, because it's not recommended to use wrap_content and autoSizeTextType at the same time. "If you set autosizing in an XML file, it is not recommended to use the value "wrap_content" for the layout_width or layout_height attributes of a TextView. It may produce unexpected results."

Comment: i dont want to use autosize at all, i prefer to munally set the size of the text, i just want it to be larger than the imageview

Comment: i tried your code and the text stays to the first line, it doesnt produce multi lines

Comment: it's hard to say what the problem it without seeing actual implementation

Comment: what yould you like to see? an image of the current implementation?

Comment: i have added images